# I am unable to get Json String object tag to JsonArray

Tags: android, json

Hi I get response from Server like this

```
     {"statusCode":200,"data":{"message":"Successfully Signed Up","userId":202}}
```

this string i am pasing this string on `JSONObject`. It is not get in `JSONArray`.

How can i get tag from this json string?

```
try {
            JSONObject jobjet = new JSONObject(result);

            Log.d("jobj",""+jobjet);

            JSONArray jsonArray = jobjet.optJSONArray("data");

            Log.d("JArray", ""+ jsonArray);

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                Log.d("Object", ""+ jsonObject);

                UserId = jsonObject.getString("userid");
                Log.d("UserId",UserId);
            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: there is no json array in your json

Comment: At the data key there is also a JSON object, not an array.

Comment: `data` is your `JSONObject` not a `JSONArray`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `data` item is not `JSONArray` it is a `JSONObject`. The Array's data has to be between those braces `[]`

The correct way to parse it is:

```
        JSONObject jobjet = new JSONObject(result);

        JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject) jobjet.optJSONObject("data");

        String msg = jsonObj.getString("message");

        String userId = jsonObj.getString("userid");
```

This is a useful [link](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/) that you can use to paste your response and check how it looks like

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
        JSONObject jobjet = new JSONObject(result);
        JSONObject jo3 =(JSONObject) jobjet.get("data");
        String msg=jo3.getString("message");
        String uId=jo3.getString("userid");
```

data is `JSONObject` not a `JSONArray`.

Answer (score 0):

Here "data" is not an JSONArray. Array will always

```
"data": [{"message":"Successfully Signed Up","userId":202},
{"message":"Successfully Signed Up","userId":202}]
```

like this..

Array will always enclose with `"[ ]"`

Answer (score 0):

first of all bro you're getting JSONArray inside a JSONObject.
Jsonarray should be something like this:

```
myArray = [ 
  {
    "first" : "John",
    "last" : "Smith"
  }, 
  {
    "first" : "Jane",
    "last" : "Doe"
  }
];
```

Therfore you have the pull the object as jsonObject and than get your data from it.